# how to check the output of init.rc (init process) in Android platform?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, system

I want to dump stack when some event happened, so I write a script to **init.rc** as below. Then I use `setprop dump_stack 0` and `setprop dump_stack 1` to rigger it,but there is no output in my console?

```
on property:dump_stack=1
       exec /system/bin/cat /proc/100/stack    # pid = 100
```

I have add some log in system\core\init\builitins.c, it says the code is work (the retstatus is 0). Even I change the script to "exec /system/bin/cat /proc/100/stack > /data/temp", it still doesn't work. So, Where is the output of init.rc (init process)?

PS. The reason I write the script to init.rc is "Permission". The init process is root, so it can dump the stack of others process.

And, is the syntax correct or not? I write the "exec /system/bin/cat /proc/100/stack" by the **Android Init Language** in http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/bring_up.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Init is writing to the kernel buffer. You can see its output with dmesg. Make sure to ramp up the loglevel in your init.rc file.